# Chrome plug-ins for Salesforce Org stopped working after implementing SSO on the Org

Tags: single-sign-on, chrome

I work on client **Salesforce** Org.

I have some useful plug-ins installed on **Chrome** like [Salesforce advanced Code searcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-advanced-code/lnkgcmpjkkkeffambkllliefdpjdklmi?hl=en).

Some days ago client have implemented SSO on the Org, now most of those plug-ins have stopped working.

Now how can I get them working again?

Comment: Is this a situation where you're logging in to a company's Active Directory network using a VPN, then log-in to their Salesforce instance via SAML SSO? If so, your client's network security settings may preclude you from re-enabling your plugins. I have clients that cause some of my plug-ins to be disabled for security reasons.

Comment: I am not logging in to the client's AD.
Logging in directly from my Chrome as I used to do earlier.